# Browser support for class syntax in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser, ecmascript-6

Below syntax,

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}


var Polygon = class {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
};



var Polygon = class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
};
```

--

is supported neither by chrome nor by firefox.

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token class(…)`

chrome version insalled `47.0.2526.80 m`

firefox version installed `44.0a2 (2015-12-12)`

Which version of browser does `class` & `extends` keywords gets supported?

Comment: Why not use something that is supported then, `function Polygon`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek class based paradigm looks more easy(close to real world) for building abstractions

Comment: I think you'll need to have strict mode on for it to work on Chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can use a javascript to javascript compiler such as Babel to compile ES6 javascript into ES5 code. It covers most of the ES6 features.
2. Take a look at https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ for a table of ES6 features and how well are they supported by different browsers.

Answer (score 3):

As of 14 Dec 2015:

- Chrome 42.0
- Firefox Gecko Nightly Build
- Edge 13
- Safari 9

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes
https://nightly.mozilla.org/

---

*Javascript **Classes** Specs:*

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-class-definitions
https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#sec-class-definitions

---

http://jshint.com/docs/options/#esnext

Comment: Any idea, How long would it take for browsers(across) to support `class` syntax?

Comment: The real question is - How long will it be before enough people have browsers that support the `class` syntax.

Comment: I am using chrome version `47.0.2526.80 m` . Does this support `class` syntax?

Comment: Yes, but only in strict mode.

Comment: Use ‘dsoop.js’. It uses the class syntax, plus much more and then converts things behind the scenes so that it is compatible for every browser!